# GitLab CI/CD pipeline not changing the code on remote server

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

I made a change to the code on GitLab repo and then, after the merge pipeline is finishing successfully, but with no change to the code in the server. How can I fix that?

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
stages:
  - publish
  - deploy

build_and_push:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: publish
  script:
    - docker system prune -a -f
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
    - docker login $REGISTRY -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_TOKEN
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
  only:
    - main

deploy:
  image: ubuntu
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod og= $SSH_KEY
    - apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client -y
    - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST docker login $REGISTRY -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_TOKEN
    - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST docker-compose pull
    - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST docker-compose down
    - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST docker-compose up -d

  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://192.168.0.130
  only:
    - main
```

My compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
  volumes:
   app:
   pg_data:

  services:
   web-app:
     env_file: .env
     image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
     ports:
       - "8000:8080"
     volumes:
       - app:/app
     command: >
       sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0:8080"
     depends_on:
       - pgdb

    pgdb:
     image: postgres:13.10
     env_file: .env
     volumes:
       - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: What do you mean by no change to code in server?

Comment: @Raghu after pull-down-up the code doesn't change

Comment: Do you mean your deployment stage isnt deploying the code to your server?

Comment: @Raghu well yeah

Comment: How does your docker-compsoe file look like? What is the $IMAGE_NAME in the docker push?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko ```version: '3'

volumes:
  app:
  pg_data:

services:
  web-app:
    env_file: .env
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
      - app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0:8080"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb

  pgdb:
    image: postgres:13.10
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data```
IMAGE_NAME is a link provided by gitlab since my image is stored on local gitlab registry

Comment: I added your compose file as an edit to the question. It's kind of important to know what is the value of the IMAGE_NAME in both .env and in the workflow, are you sure they match 1:1? Also, do you get any logs from the compose commands in gitlab?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko I couldn't add my compose to the question body bc it says my question is mostly code.. Gitlab log output after the `pull` is here: `https://pastebin.com/6WzZAgGy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is your volume configuration:

```
  volumes:
   app:
     ...
     volumes:
       - app:/app
```

What you are doing is creating a named volume `app` and mounting it to the container. I assume you also have in your Dockerfile something like this:

```
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
```

Or along those lines. So in other words, you build an image that contains a directory called app. But in your compose file you overwrite that directory with whatever is in the named volume `app` in your host machine. And the content of that volume is whatever was available in the first version of the image.

Remove this from your docker-compose.yml

```
 volumes:
   - app:/app
```

and you should be OK.